# Grails access domain data during service initialization

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to implement a search service where i want to do some initial data caching when the service is created.  The service implements the spring framework InitializingBean interface, but when I try to use the afterPropertiesSet method to get data from my domains, I get an error stating that GORM is not ready for use.  Is there any way to have domain objects available for use in the afterPropertiesSet method?  Grails 2.5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of an event or something similar to notify when domain classes have been initialized, but it does happen before BootStrap runs. For cases like this where `afterPropertiesSet` is too early to do something, you can dependency-inject the service in BootStrap and call your own init method, e.g.

```
class BootStrap {

   def myService

   def init = {
      myService.init()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Burt.  That's what I figured, but was hoping there was some other way.